# FSMO roles in LDS

Tags: ad-lds, fsmo

Does MS LDS (LDAP) have the same 5 FSMO roles that AD does? When I check in dsmgmt I'm only seeing that 2 roles are known by my LDS servers (Schema and Naming Master). Just curious if I should be seeing the other 3 roles.  By the way, this is for 2016 and 2022 versions of LDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not include the other 3 roles.

> Since a DC operating as AD LDS does not host domain NCs, it cannot own any of the three roles contained by domain NCs. It can own the Schema Master and Domain Naming FSMO roles.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/bf8afb5f-1ae0-45de-8445-8a717ea5124a